# Filter by Job Status in BigQuery CLI

Tags: google-bigquery

How do I return a list of **RUNNING** jobs using the [BigQuery CLI](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-jobs#view-job)

This doesn't work `bq ls -j -a --filter='states:RUNNING'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [filter flag](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference#bq_ls) with `state:[STATE]`is applied for the transfer runs. Also, the `--filter` flag is to filter [labels](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-managing-labels#what-are-labels).

A workaround for this could be running the command `bq ls -j -a | grep RUNNING` in case you're using a Linux CL, or you could run a curl command to call the BigQuery API. For instance:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" 'https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/<Your Project>/jobs?alt=json&allUsers=true&projection=full&stateFilter=RUNNING'
```

Additionally, you could filling a [Feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=1162685) to the BigQuery engineering team to consider having the option to filter the running jobs by using the `bq ls -j` command